# In R, how can I validate whether values are valid according to an external table?

Tags: r, validation, tidyr

I have a reference table of acceptable column values, represented as `good_df` below.  I want to use it to find out which values in the previously unseen `test_df` are not among the list of acceptable ones.

```r
library(tidyverse)
good_df <- tribble(
  ~column, ~value,
  "col1", "a",
  "col1", "b",
  "col1", "c",
  "col1", "d",
  "col1", "e",
  "col2", "A",
  "col2", "B",
  "col2", "C"
)

set.seed(1)
test_df <- tibble(
  col1 = sample(letters[1:3], 4, T),
  col2 = c(sample(LETTERS[1:3], 3, T), "D"),  # The D is invalid.
  col3 = rnorm(4)
)
test_df
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   col1  col2    col3
#>   <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 a     A      0.330
#> 2 c     C     -0.820
#> 3 a     C      0.487
#> 4 b     D      0.738
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

My thought is to use `pivot_longer` to convert `test_df` to a format that matches `good_df`, and then use `setdiff` to see what remains after the valid rows are removed, which must be the invalid ones. Something along the lines of this below, producing `expected_output`.

```
long_test_df <- pivot_longer(test_df, "MAGIC HAPPENS HERE") 

long_test_df %>% 
  select(column, value) %>% 
  setdiff(good_df)

expected_output <- tribble(
  ~column, ~value,
  "col2", "D",
)
```

I can't seem to get `pivot_longer` to work as I'm intending it. Maybe it's not designed to?  I also thought of using the validate package, but I don't see anything in the documentation about explicitly listing allowed or forbidden values in creating the rules, unless I missed something.

Also of course, in practice I have many more acceptable column/value pairs and many more columns in my data sets to validate.

I am open to alternatives to my approach and to alternative forms of storing the set of allowed column values.  How may I achieve this? (Bonus points for pretty pipes and fewer named variables!)

#### Edit - Solution:

A modified version of Jonathan's answer gives the fully general solution. (Also, I still prefer `setdiff` to `anti_join` here, although that's just a personal preference.)

```
test_df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = any_of(good_df$column), names_to = "column", values_to = "value") %>% 
  select(column, value) %>% 
  anti_join(good_df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for `pivot_longer`, the missing values can be obtained with `anti_join`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

test_df %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(col1, col2), names_to = "column", values_to = "value") %>% 
  anti_join(good_df)
```

Comment: This looks like a great start, but I'm concerned about referencing `c(col1, col2)` directly.  I probably should have said this, but I actually want to build a function that doesn't know in advance which columns are present in `test_df`.  

`test_df` won't necessarily contain all, or even any of the columns which would need validating.  

Wait, I got it.  Using `cols = any_of(good_df$column)` does the job.  I'll lay out details in the original post and accept this answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might additionally consider this approach

```
cn = unique(good_df$column)
melt(test_df[,..cn], measure=cn,variable = "column")[!good_df, on=.(column, value)]
```

Output:

```
   column value
1:   col2     D
```

where `test_df` and `good_df` are of class `data.table`. That is:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(good_df); setDT(test_df)
```